# How do I modify my pivot query so that rows with null values are not excluded in the output?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-null

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have the following `T-SQL` query for pivoting my data:

```
SELECT *

FROM    

(
SELECT  

[PropertyCode],    
FORMAT([MTH], 'MMM') AS 'MthTxt',
[FY],    
ISNULL((SUM([Revenue])/SUM([GN])),0) AS 'RevByGN',    
[Market]   

FROM View1

WHERE [MTH] BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2020-06-01'

AND [PropertyCode] = 'ABC'

GROUP BY [PropertyCode], [MTH], [FY], [Market]

) AS SourceTable

PIVOT
(
   AVG([RevByGN])
 FOR [MthTxt] IN ([Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec], [Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun])
) AS PivotTable
```

An extract of the output is shown below:[image: output]

My issue is with the highlighted Markets, namely China and Russia. Since there are no data for FY 19-20, the pivot results are not including the FY 19-20 rows for these 2 Markets.

How can I force my Pivot results to include those rows?
I would also like to like `NULL` values to be shown as `0`.

Adding what I have done so far based on Shnugo's solution:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_table (
    PropertyCode nvarchar(15),
    FY nvarchar(10),
    Market nvarchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO #temp_table VALUES
('CDM', 'FY 18-19', 'France'),
('CDM', 'FY 18-19', 'United Kingdom'),
('CDM', 'FY 18-19', 'Germany'),
('CDM', 'FY 18-19', 'Reunion'),
('CDM', 'FY 18-19', 'South Africa'),
('CDM', 'FY 18-19', 'Russia'),
('CDM', 'FY 18-19', 'Middle East'),
('CDM', 'FY 19-20', 'France'),
('CDM', 'FY 19-20', 'United Kingdom'),
('CDM', 'FY 19-20', 'Germany'),
('CDM', 'FY 19-20', 'Reunion'),
('CDM', 'FY 19-20', 'South Africa'),
('CDM', 'FY 19-20', 'Russia'),
('CDM', 'FY 19-20', 'Middle East')

;WITH temp1 AS

(
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [PropertyCode] FROM #temp_table
      GROUP BY [PropertyCode]) t1
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT [FY] FROM #temp_table
                   GROUP BY [FY]) t2
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT [Market] FROM #temp_table
                   GROUP BY [Market]) t3
)

SELECT PivotTable.*

FROM

(
SELECT 
a.[PropertyCode],
a.[FY],
a.[Market],
ISNULL((SUM(b.[Package Revenue Excl VAT])/SUM(b.[GN])),0) AS 'GADR',
FORMAT(b.[MTH], 'MMM') AS 'MthTxt'

FROM [temp1] a
LEFT JOIN [QueryType2_v06feb2019_TBL] b ON (b.PropertyCode = a.PropertyCode AND b.FY = a.FY AND b.Market = a.Market)

WHERE b.[MTH] BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2020-06-01'

GROUP BY a.[PropertyCode], b.[MTH], a.[FY], a.[Market]

)AS SourceTable

PIVOT
(
   AVG([GADR])
 FOR [MthTxt] IN ([Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec], [Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun])
) AS PivotTable
```

Still not working and giving me the following results:

[image: output 2]

Answer (score 0):

For your next question I'd ask you to create a MCVE to reproduce your issue. The minimum was some sample data, best provided as DDL and DML.

I've done this for you this time. This is not your exact problem, but it will help to demonstrate the approach.

First we need a *mockup table* with some data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, GroupID INT, SubId CHAR(1),Sub2Id CHAR(1), SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'a','x','a with x is First in 1')
,(1,'b','y','b with y is Second in 1')
,(1,'c','z','c with z is Third in 1')
,(2,'b','x','b with x is First in 2')
,(2,'c','z','c with z is Second in 2')
,(3,'a','y','a with y is First in 3');
```

--This query has the issue you are talking about:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM
(
    SELECT tbl.SubId
          ,tbl.GroupID
          ,tbl.Sub2Id
          ,tbl.SomeValue
    FROM @tbl tbl
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(SomeValue) FOR SubId IN(a,b,c)
) p
ORDER BY GroupId,Sub2Id;
```

The result

```
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| GroupID | Sub2Id | a                      | b                       | c                       |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1       | x      | a with x is First in 1 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1       | y      | NULL                   | b with y is Second in 1 | NULL                    |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1       | z      | NULL                   | NULL                    | c with z is Third in 1  |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2       | x      | NULL                   | b with x is First in 2  | NULL                    |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2       | z      | NULL                   | NULL                    | c with z is Second in 2 |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3       | y      | a with y is First in 3 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

You can see, that each GroupId is mentioned as often as there is data. Group 1 is represented in 3 rows x,y and z, while 2 shows up with z and x and 3 only with y.

What you need, is a fixed set with all rows you want to see in any case. If you can be sure, that any combination you want to see exists at least once in your set, you can extract this from the data directly, otherwise you'd have to maintain a table providing such a fix set. In the example I assume, that the existing data can provide all what I need.

```
--Create a combination of all existing Groups *cross joined* with all existing subs.
WITH AllCombinations AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT GroupID FROM @tbl GROUP BY GroupID) t1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT Sub2Id FROM @tbl GROUP BY Sub2Id) t2
)
SELECT p.* 
FROM
(
    SELECT tbl.SubId
          ,combos.GroupID
          ,combos.Sub2Id
          ,tbl.SomeValue
    FROM AllCombinations combos
    LEFT JOIN @tbl tbl ON combos.GroupID=tbl.GroupID AND combos.Sub2Id=tbl.Sub2Id
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(SomeValue) FOR SubId IN(a,b,c)
) p
ORDER BY GroupId,Sub2Id;
```

You see, that I `LEFT JOIN` the combination set with the actual table. And I pick the values with the `combos` alias and not with `tbl`. This will ensure, that these values are within the resulting set and will show up in the pivoted list.

The result

```
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| GroupID | Sub2Id | a                      | b                       | c                       |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1       | x      | a with x is First in 1 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1       | y      | NULL                   | b with y is Second in 1 | NULL                    |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1       | z      | NULL                   | NULL                    | c with z is Third in 1  |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2       | x      | NULL                   | b with x is First in 2  | NULL                    |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2       | y      | NULL                   | NULL                    | NULL                    |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2       | z      | NULL                   | NULL                    | c with z is Second in 2 |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3       | x      | NULL                   | NULL                    | NULL                    |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3       | y      | a with y is First in 3 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3       | z      | NULL                   | NULL                    | NULL                    |
+---------+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

### UPDATE

I tried to fix your query, but I cannot test it. So this is flying blindfolded through a dense forest in the middle of the night ;-)

```
CREATE TABLE #propCodes (PropertyCode nvarchar(15));
CREATE TABLE #FYs (FY nvarchar(10));
CREATE TABLE #Markets(Market nvarchar(255));

INSERT INTO #propCodes VALUES('CDM');
INSERT INTO #FYs VALUES('FY 18-19'),('FY 19-20');
INSERT INTO #Markets VALUES
('France'),
('United Kingdom'),
('Germany'),
('Reunion'),
('South Africa'),
('Russia'),
('Middle East'),
('France');

/* Check this to see the *cartesian product*
SELECT *
FROM #propCodes
CROSS JOIN #FYs 
CROSS JOIN #Markets;
*/

;WITH temp1 AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #propCodes
    CROSS JOIN #FYs 
    CROSS JOIN #Markets
)
,Aggregated AS
(
    SELECT 
        [PropertyCode],
        [FY],
        [Market],
        ISNULL((SUM([Package Revenue Excl VAT])/SUM([GN])),0) AS 'GADR',
        FORMAT([MTH], 'MMM') AS 'MthTxt'
    FROM [QueryType2_v06feb2019_TBL]
    WHERE [MTH] BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2020-06-01'
    GROUP BY [PropertyCode], [MTH], a.[FY], [Market]
)
SELECT PivotTable.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [temp1] a
    LEFT JOIN Aggregated b ON (b.PropertyCode = a.PropertyCode AND b.FY = a.FY AND b.Market = a.Market)
)AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
   AVG([GADR])  FOR [MthTxt] IN ([Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec], [Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun])
) AS PivotTable;
```

I replaced your single temp table by tree easy to maintain tables. Check the out-commented SELECT to see what happens...

And I introduced one more CTE to separate your aggregations/computations from the pivoting the `LEFT JOIN`.

Good luck. If this does not work, please provide sample data in consumable format reduced to the needed minimum...

Comment: Thanks. However I am a bit confused. I would like to create a table (as you mentioned) but my confusion lies in the variables that need to be in this table. I guess it should contain PropertyCode, FY and Market. I would then pick those variables from the newly created table and LEFT JOIN my View1 to retrieve the remaining variables.

Comment: @user3115933 I don't know your data... You can create dedicated tables per dimension and `CROSS JOIN` them. You can mix both approaches and pick some data (e.g. PropertyCode) from the live data and other (like the FY) from a table ensuring the result to be complete.

Comment: The key here is the CROSS JOIN?

Comment: @user3115933 short ago I answered [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56054200/5089204). Might be worth to read.

Comment: I have created a table with a list of all Property Codes (9 values) and their corresponding FY values (FY 18-19 and FY 19-20) and Markets (21 values). So I end up in this table with (9*2*21) 378 rows and 3 columns (PropertyCode, FY, Market).

Comment: @user3115933 Is your last comment a question? If the row count you find is as expected this will be fine...

Comment: Not a question. I was just explaining what I did based on your solution. However, this is still giving me a headache! I created the table with the fixed values but those rows are still not showing. May be show some data if you don't mind having another look...

Comment: I have added what I have done so far based on your solution.

Comment: @user3115933 See my udpate